# _T( ) macro changes for UNICODE character data

Tags: c++, c, string, gcc, widechar

I have UNICODE application where in we use _T(x) which is defined as follows.

```
#if defined(_UNICODE)
#define _T(x) L ##x
#else
#define _T(x) x
#endif
```

I understand that L gets defined to wchar_t, which will be 4 bytes on any platform. Please correct me if I am wrong. My requirement is that I need L to be 2 bytes. So as compiler hack I started using -fshort-wchar gcc flag. But now I need my application to be moved to zSeries where I don't get to see the effect of -fshort-wchar flag in that platform.

In order for me to be able to port my application on zSeries, I need to modify _T( ) macro in such a way that even after using L ##x and without using -fshort-wchar flag, I need to get 2byte wide character data.Can some one tell me how I can change the definition of L so that I can define L to be 2 bytes always in my application.

Comment: AFAIK, wchar_t is 2bytes wide on Windows, so the size of wchar_t is implementation dependant.

Comment: `wchar_t` is normally used as the base type for `WCHAR`, which certainly is 2 bytes wide. Functions like `MessageBoxW` have `WCHAR*` arguments, so having `WCHAR` and `wchar_t` identical makes Windows programming a a lot easier.

Comment: L is just the character 'L'. It doesn't get defined to be anything. In C++, L"hello world" just defines a *wide string literal*. But the L doesn't get replaced by anything.

Answer (score 5):

You can't - not without c++0x support. c++0x defines the following ways of declaring string literals:

- "string of char characters in some implementation defined encoding" - char
- u8"String of utf8 chars" - char
- u"string of utf16 chars" - char16_t
- U"string of utf32 chars" - char32_t
- L"string of wchar_t in some implementation defined encoding" - wchar_t

Until c++0x is widely supported, the only way to encode a utf-16 string in a cross platform way is to break it up into bits:

```
// make a char16_t type to stand in until msvc/gcc/etc supports
// c++0x utf string literals
#ifndef CHAR16_T_DEFINED
#define CHAR16_T_DEFINED
typedef unsigned short char16_t;
#endif

const char16_t strABC[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
// the same declaration would work for a type that changes from 8 to 16 bits:

#ifdef _UNICODE
typedef char16_t TCHAR;
#else
typedef char TCHAR;
#endif
const TCHAR strABC2[] = { 'a', 'b', 'b', '\0' };
```

The _T macro can only deliver the goods on platforms where wchar_t's are 16bits wide. And, the alternative is still not truly cross-platform: The coding of char and wchar_t is implementation defined so 'a' does not necessarily encode the unicode codepoint for 'a' (0x61). Thus, to be strictly accurate, this is the only way of writing the string:

```
const TCHAR strABC[] = { '\x61', '\x62', '\x63', '\0' };
```

Which is just horrible.

Comment: Mind you, on an IBM zSeries `a` is still equal to `0x61`, but `j` is not `0x6a`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! The wonders of portability :-)

If you have a C99 compiler for all your platforms, use `int_least16_t`, `uint_least16_t`, ... from `<stdint.h>`. Most platforms also define `int16_t` but it's not required to exist (if the platform is capable of using exactly 16 bits at a time, the typedef `int16_t` must be defined).

Now wrap all the strings in arrays of `uint_least16_t` and make sure your code does not expect values of `uint_least16_t` to wrap at 65535 ...

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem - you still don't have a way to create `const uint_least16_t[]` literals.

Comment: I am using GCC compiler. Is there any other GCC compiler flag other than -fshort-wchar to change the size of wchar_t.

Comment: @MSalters: `const uint_least16_t data[] = { 'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', '\0' };`

Comment: did you spot the "I need to modify `_T( )` macro" part of the question? How does `_T("foobar")` expand to `const uint_least16_t data[] = { 'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', '\0' };` ?

Comment: You want two incompatible things: at least one of the things has to compromise --- the computer is much more stubborn than you