# defining wchar_t to 2byte

Tags: c, wchar-t, zseries

In my application I always need wchar_t to be 2 byte. I know -fshort-wchar can do this. But I can't use this on zSeries. is there any other way to define wchar_t to 2 byte?

Comment: possible duplicate of [_T( ) macro changes for UNICODE character data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133144/t-macro-changes-for-unicode-character-data)

Answer (score 1):

No. `wchar_t` is implementation defined. You have no control over it.

Don't rely on implementation defined types. Rely on Standard (C99 `<inttypes.h>`) types instead.

---

What's wrong with the question [_T( ) macro changes for UNICODE character data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4133144/25324)?